# Magento 2: Add a custom link in myaccount dashboard

Tags: magento2, customer-account, dashboard

I wants to add a custom link in my account dashboard, and that link redirects to specified phtml file in magento2.

How to add specified controller to this.

Controller:

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Customer;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   /**
  * Index Action*
  * @return void
  */
  public function execute()
  {
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

test_customer_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
        <title>My Blog Post</title>
    </head>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Blog Post</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="module_customer" template="Vendor_Module::loy_rew.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-nscore-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Blog Post</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/customer</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: Is it working or not ? @shivashankarm

Comment: Hi @Rohan sorry for the late reply

Comment: Its still redirecting to "Whoops, our bad... " page.

Comment: Can you please upload your xml, controller and phtml code? So, I can easily find your issue and solve it.

Comment: Hi @Roshan Please find my updated question

Comment: It should be module_customer_index.xml instead of test_customer_index.xml

Comment: Yes , i have changed this

Comment: remove var/ geneation folder after change and check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85329/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-shivashankar-m).

Answer (score 2):

Create **customer_account.xml** file in `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="customer-account-navigation-blog-link"  destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-blog-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Blog Post</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">blog/customer</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create controller **Index.php** at `/app/code/VendorName/Blog/Controller/Customer/`

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Blog\Controller\Customer;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   /**
  * Index Action*
  * @return void
  */
  public function execute()
  {
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

Create **blog_customer_index.xml** layout file at `/app/code/VendorName/Blog/view/frontend/layout/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
        <title>My Blog Post</title>
    </head>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Blog Post</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blog_customer" template="VendorName_ModuleName::yourphtml.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create **yourphtml.phtml** file at `/app/code/VendorName/Blog/view/frontend/templates/`

```
<h1> File call successfully </h1>
```

> My Blog Post => Your tab lable
>
> blog/customer => Your controller path

Comment: Thanks @Rohan , iam able to add a link by using above code ,but when I click on that link it's redirected to whoops bad page, how to add a specified phtml to that link

Comment: Did you create controller which you add in path ?

Comment: Yes , i have created a controller file

Comment: Can you please upload your controller and xml file code in question?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: @RohanHapani I followed above steps and I do see 'My Blog Post' link pointing to blog/customer URL but it's not rendering the content. Do we need to do anything so that the Index.php controller is called to render given .phtml file?

Comment: @RohanHapani, my module name is Customer, so named the xml file as customer_customer_index.xml inside vendorname/Customer/view/frontend/layout.

Comment: @RohanHapani, my module name is Customer, so named the xml file as customer_customer_index.xml inside vendorname/Customer/view/frontend/layout.

Comment: nerve mind, I didn't have routes.xml and the layout file name was not matching the controller path in customer_account.xml. It's working now once those are fixed.